# Plotting Ellipse for complex values in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, ellipse

I am trying to plot the elliptical trajectory of a particle, but my matlab code runs and gives me warning that I m trying to plot imaginary values. How can I remove this error?
My Matlab code is as follows:

```
    % plot of trajectory of the particle in flexural gravity wave
    U =5;
    t=1;
    y1=0;
    h=50;
    k=2*pi/100;
    w=pi;
    X= (-80*pi:pi:80*pi);
    Y= (-80*pi:pi:80*pi); 
    H=1;
    A= (H/2)*cosh(k*(h+y1))/sinh(k*h);
    B= (H/2)*sinh(k*(h+y1))/sinh(k*h); 
    Y = B.* ((1-((X-U*t)./A).^2).^(1/2));
    plot(X,Y);
    xlabel('X');
    ylabel('Y');
```

The warning matlab shows is:
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot imaginary number only,
Please change the code,  `plot(X,Y);` as `plot(X,imag(Y))`.

In case of real value, `plot(X,real(Y))`.

If you are interested in magnitude of complex number,  `plot(X,abs(Y))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am trying to plot real values.

Comment: In that case, plot(X,real(Y))

Comment: But, your real values of Y are all zero, and even though you use plot(X,Y), matlab automatically plots real value only with a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question.
I can plot it by using general coordinates of the ellipse, ie, using x=a*cos(t) and y=a*sin(t). and that really worked.

```
% plot of trajectory of the particle in flexural gravity wave
U = 5;
t = 1;
y1 = 0;
h = 50;
k = 2*pi/100;
w = pi;
x0 = U*t;
y0 = 0;
H = 1;
A = (H/2)*cosh(k*(h+y1))/sinh(k*h);
B = (H/2)*sinh(k*(h+y1))/sinh(k*h); 
z = -2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
X = x0 + A*cos(z);
Y = y0 + B*sin(z);
plot(X,Y);
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
```